# When accessing the web, what is the different between block and without block

Tags: ios, networking, asihttprequest, objective-c-blocks

I am using ASIHTTPRequest framework, in the [document](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use), what are the differences between the 2nd and 3rd example, in **usage**, **advantage** and **disadvantage**?

2nd example (Creating an asynchronous request):

```
- (IBAction)grabURLInBackground:(id)sender
{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
// Use when fetching text data
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

// Use when fetching binary data
NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
NSError *error = [request error];
}
```

3rd example (Using blocks)

```
- (IBAction)grabURLInBackground:(id)sender
{
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
   __block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setCompletionBlock:^{
      // Use when fetching text data
      NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

      // Use when fetching binary data
      NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
   }];
   [request setFailedBlock:^{
      NSError *error = [request error];
   }];
   [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blocks in iOS are a part of [Concurrent Programming](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

You use a block when you want to create units of work (that is, code segments) that can be passed around as though they are **values**. Blocks are usually used for writting a **callbacks**.

Usually, using blocks do not reflect in different applicatino behaviour. The syntactical difference is that, when using blocks you do not need to define a request delegate or implement delegate methods (such as `-requestFinished:` and `-requestFailed:`) for async requests.

One of the advantages is in accessing local method variables in completion block, bacause the function expression in block can reference and can preserve **access to local variables** (like variable `url` in your method `-grabURLInBackground:` or any other local variable defined in your method).

The second adventage is in using nested request calls. For example, you may need to perform a few requests in sequence, and without blocks you will need to define a separate delegate method callback for each request, which may result in reduced readability of your code.

Blocks allow you to write code at the point of invocation that is **executed later in the context of the method implementation**, which may be very usefull, when you get used to using them.

Some patterns to avoid when using blocks are mentioned in [Apple Blocks Programming Topis](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH5-SW6)